# Grid of histograms according to filtered data

Tags: matplotlib, subplot

Consider this kind of data file:

**data-file.txt**

```
75,15,1,57.5,9.9,5
75,15,1,58.1,10.0,5
75,15,2,37.9,8.3,5
75,15,2,18.2,7.3,5
150,15,1,26.4,8.3,10
150,15,1,31.6,7.9,10
150,15,2,30.6,7.5,10
150,15,2,25.1,7.1,10
```

Observe that 3rd column values are only `1,2`.

I would like to produce `3x2`-grid of histograms. The subplots below looks right, but each row should contain 2 histograms from different data set, I mean, I filter the data according to last column.

The important code is `ax.hist(X[ (y==grp) & (X[:,2]==1), cols],` where the filter occurs.

I want 2 histograms on each row:

- the 1st row with `(X[:,2]== * )` where `*` being any value from 3rd column (1 or 2),
- the 2nd row with `(X[:,2]==1)` and
- the 3rd row with `(X[:,2]==2)`.

In resume, I expect to get on 2nd, 3rd rows histograms for the filtered data:

**3rd column value = 1**

```
75,15,1,57.5,9.9,5
75,15,1,58.1,10.0,5
150,15,1,26.4,8.3,10
150,15,1,31.6,7.9,10
```

**3rd column value = 2**

```
75,15,2,37.9,8.3,5
75,15,2,18.2,7.3,5
150,15,2,30.6,7.5,10
150,15,2,25.1,7.1,10
```

**Code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from itertools import combinations

data_file='data-file.txt'

df = pd.io.parsers.read_csv(
    filepath_or_buffer=data_file,
    delim_whitespace=False,
    )

M, N = df.shape[0], df.shape[1]

feature_dict = {i+1:label for i,label in zip(
                range(N),
                  ('L',
                   'A',
                   'G',
                   'P',
                   'T', 
                   'PP',
                   ))}

df.columns = [l for i,l in sorted(feature_dict.items())] 

X = df[range(N-1)].values
y = df['PP'].values

label_dict = dict(enumerate(sorted(list(set(y)))))
label_dict = {x+1:y for x,y in label_dict.iteritems()}
num_grupos = len(label_dict.keys())

grps_to_hist_list = [[j for j in i] for i in combinations(label_dict.keys(), 2)]
grps_to_hist_list_values = [[j for j in i] for i in combinations(label_dict.values(), 2)]

cols_to_hist = [3, 4] 

for grps_to_hist in grps_to_hist_list:
    grps_str = [ label_dict[grps_to_hist[0]], label_dict[grps_to_hist[1]] ]
    print 'creating histogram for groups %s from data file %s' % (grps_str , data_file)
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=2, figsize=(18,8))

    for ax,cols  in zip(axes.ravel(), cols_to_hist):
        # set bin sizes
        min_b = math.floor(np.min(X[:,cols]))
        max_b = math.ceil(np.max(X[:,cols]))
        bins = np.linspace(min_b, max_b, 40)


        # ploting the histograms
        #"""
        for grp,color in zip( grps_str, ('blue', 'red')):
                ax.hist(X[ (y==grp) & (X[:,2]==1), cols],
                       color=color,
                       label='%s'  % grp,
                       bins=bins,
                       alpha=0.3,)

        ylims = ax.get_ylim()

        # plot annotation
        leg = ax.legend(loc='upper right', fancybox=True, fontsize=8)
        leg.get_frame().set_alpha(0.5)
        ax.set_ylim([0, max(ylims)+2])
        ax.set_xlabel(feature_dict[cols+1])
        ax.set_title('%s' % str(data_file))

        # hide axis ticks
        ax.tick_params(axis="both", which="both", bottom="off", top="off", labelbottom="on", left="off", right="off", labelleft="on")

        # remove axis spines
        ax.spines["top"].set_visible(False)  
        ax.spines["right"].set_visible(False)
        ax.spines["bottom"].set_visible(False)
        ax.spines["left"].set_visible(False)
        #"""

    fig.tight_layout()       

    plt.show()
```

Here is a screen-shot from the code above with the filter **`(y==grp) & (X[:,2]==1)`** (which should be on 2nd row).

[image]

Comment: I think you misunderstood the reasoning behind a [mcve]. You should **create** a [mcve] **because** you have a huge file which you cannot share. In this case it looks like the minimal example could simply use some random numbers `np.random.randint`.  Because we're missing important variables like `grps_to_hist_list`,  `cols_to_hist` or `label_dict`  it is very hard to help you here.

Comment: Got `KeyError: 'Prop'` for line 33. Honestly, don't understand what your expected result is. I guess you know this and this is probably not your question. But if you're wondering why the 2nd and 3rd rows don't have plot, that's because your `zip( grps_str, ('blue', 'red'))` has only 2 elements. If you're wondering why the condition `y == grp` doesn't work, maybe you can correct the KeyError and it might be easier for others to understand what is `y`.

Comment: Eh, have you even tried yourself? At least `TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'` for me... Besides, providing more details about your expected results might be helpful. My overall feeling is don't know how to help. Leave to experts... Sorry...

Comment: Gave an answer below since no experts showed up yet. Not sure if this is what you want though. General idea is to loop over rows with corresponding masks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My logic is to iterate over rows with corresponding masks of your choice, `[(X[:,2]==1) | (X[:,2]==2), X[:,2]==1, X[:,2]==2]`. Hopefully this is what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from itertools import combinations

data_file='data-file.txt'

df = pd.io.parsers.read_csv(
    filepath_or_buffer=data_file,
    delim_whitespace=False,
    )

M, N = df.shape[0], df.shape[1]

feature_dict = {i+1:label for i,label in zip(
                range(N),
                  ('L',
                   'A',
                   'G',
                   'P',
                   'T', 
                   'PP',
                   ))}

df.columns = [l for i,l in sorted(feature_dict.items())] 

X = df[range(N-1)].values
y = df['PP'].values

label_dict = dict(enumerate(sorted(list(set(y)))))
label_dict = {x+1:y for x,y in label_dict.iteritems()}
num_grupos = len(label_dict.keys())

grps_to_hist_list = [[j for j in i] for i in combinations(label_dict.keys(), 2)]
grps_to_hist_list_values = [[j for j in i] for i in combinations(label_dict.values(), 2)]

cols_to_hist = [3, 4] 

for grps_to_hist in grps_to_hist_list:
    grps_str = [ label_dict[grps_to_hist[0]], label_dict[grps_to_hist[1]] ]
    print 'creating histogram for groups %s from data file %s' % (grps_str , data_file)
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=2, figsize=(18,8))

    for row_ax, row_mask in zip(axes, [(X[:,2]==1) | (X[:,2]==2), X[:,2]==1, X[:,2]==2]):
        for ax,cols  in zip(row_ax, cols_to_hist):
            # set bin sizes
            min_b = math.floor(np.min(X[:,cols]))
            max_b = math.ceil(np.max(X[:,cols]))
            bins = np.linspace(min_b, max_b, 40)


            # ploting the histograms
            #"""
            for grp,color in zip( grps_str, ('blue', 'red')):
                    ax.hist(X[ (y==grp) & row_mask, cols],
                           color=color,
                           label='%s'  % grp,
                           bins=bins,
                           alpha=0.3,)

            ylims = ax.get_ylim()

            # plot annotation
            leg = ax.legend(loc='upper right', fancybox=True, fontsize=8)
            leg.get_frame().set_alpha(0.5)
            ax.set_ylim([0, max(ylims)+2])
            ax.set_xlabel(feature_dict[cols+1])
            ax.set_title('%s' % str(data_file))

            # hide axis ticks
            ax.tick_params(axis="both", which="both", bottom="off", top="off", labelbottom="on", left="off", right="off", labelleft="on")

            # remove axis spines
            ax.spines["top"].set_visible(False)  
            ax.spines["right"].set_visible(False)
            ax.spines["bottom"].set_visible(False)
            ax.spines["left"].set_visible(False)
            #"""

    fig.tight_layout()       

    plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I think your indent level is different from mine. I use 4 whitespaces for indentation. If you use 3, try change it and hopefully that works.